# Google maps store locator without map

Tags: php, javascript, xml, google-maps, search

I'm essentially trying to build a kind of store locator using Google Maps geocoder, but I want to find a way to write code that returns the nearest stores as hyperlinks on the page (probably inside a div), without placing everything on a map. I don't want to use a map, or markers and infowindows, etc... at least not to begin with.

I've followed a lot of the Google Maps API tutorials online, and it's been easy enough to build a basic working store locator that returns a set number of results inside a given radius by checking the input latlng against the values in my database, but I'm not all that skilled at js, and was wondering if anyone knew of any tutorials that might demonstrate the use of the geocoder for returning latlng search results just in text format, without a map.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the [Google geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) is not allowed without using the results on a Google Map.

> Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google
>   map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.
>   For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of
>   Service License Restrictions.

Comment: That's what I thought may be the case. Thanks. Any other decent geocoders anyone can recommend?